# Sanitize MS Access query using Regex

Tags: regex, ms-access

I want to sanitize (escape special characters) in a MS Access query, having these fields:
('''2', 'Last Motion', '', 'DooMotion Plugin', 1, '-', True, #12/30/2012 07:55:00#, #12/30/2012 07:55:00#, #01/1/2001 00:00:00#)

The special characters and how they are escaped are listed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826763/en-us.
In short the special characters are:  ? @ " ' # % ~ ; [ ] { } ( ) and the can be escaped by putting them into brackets [].

My question is if it is possible to sanitize a whole query using regex in one time. If yes, please show an example.

If it is not possible, then I could break it down to field level and sanitize each field seperately. How to do this with regex.

Regards,
Joost.

Comment: that special characters (and brackets as a solution) is for field names, and you're working with field values (for values, the answer is usually "don't try to sanitize anything, use query parameters instead")

Comment: Thanks Anton, I did overlook that difference.

Answer (score 0):

To follow Anton's advice, how do I use query parameters in .NET? This is the code I am currently using:

```
objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCatalog = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
objConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabase)
objCatalog.activeConnection = objConn
sql = "INSERT INTO Devices (Code, Name) VALUES ("'" & fCode & "','" & fName & "')"
objConn.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who want to know the solution to use parameters in .NET, here is the code:

```
Dim queryString As String = "INSERT INTO Devices (name, version) VALUES (@Name, @Version)"
' Open database connection.
Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(queryString)
    ' Strongly typed.
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@Version", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
    command.Connection = connection 'Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection

    ' Open the connection and execute the insert command.
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using 'The connection is automatically closed when the code exits the Using block
```

Again, thanks Anton for pointing me to the correct solution.